# Rails custom validation error message not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My understanding is that I can customize error messages in the localization files. I'm currently trying to customize the error message for an invalid username field on my User model:

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :username,    length: { within: 3..25 },
                            format: /\A(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d]+\Z/i,
                            uniqueness: true
```

**en.yml (localization file)**

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            username:
              format: "CUSTOM MESSAGE!"
```

The error message I receive, however, is the default "is invalid" message (or "Username is invalid" if I get the `full_messages` version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml). There is no `format` key in the `errors/messages`. You need to override the `invalid` key.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            username:
              invalid: "CUSTOM MESSAGE!"
```